# how to appear a text when click the button action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

how to appear a text when click the button in action script ?
How to disappear a text when click the button using action script ?

Please let me know how to do this with ACTION SCRIPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var TextBoxExample:TextField = new TextField();
stage.addChild(TextBoxExample);
TextBoxExample.text = "Example Text!";
TextBoxExample.visible=true;

ExampleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
if(TextBoxExample.visible==true){
TextBoxExample.visible=false;
}else{
TextBoxExample.visible=true;
}
});
```

Comment: **Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 1: Statement must appear within on handler
var TextBoxExample:TextField = new TextField();


**Error** Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 1, frame=1:Line 6: The class or interface 'Event' could not be loaded.
kotubutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(MouseEvent:Event):void{

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in my code, i edited it, works proper now.

Comment: Can you mail me your sample to samithahewawasam@gmail.com